# I have 2 if statements in one, the first is being skipped, why?

Tags: ios, if-statement

Hi there I'm having trouble using multiple if statements. Here is my code:

```
if ([itemOnSpecial caseInsensitiveCompare: @"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    specialLabel.text = specialPrice;
    [specialLabel setHidden:NO]; 
    }
//This statement is completely skipped

if ([isOnBulkSpecial caseInsensitiveCompare:@"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
            UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
            specialLabel.text = bulkSpecialPrice;
            [specialLabel setHidden:NO]; 

}else{
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    [specialLabel setHidden:YES];
}
```

Only the second if statement is taken into account. The first if statement seems to be completely disregarded.

Comment: maybe u only think the first if statement is skipped because you override the value in the specialLabel.text in the second if as well?

Comment: try putting else part into first if block.

Comment: How do i not override the value of specialLabel.text in the second one?

Comment: @Shayno specialLabel.text = bulkSpecialPrice;, btw, when you want to comment to someone specific, use the "@" and his name without whitespaces, otherwise he wouldn't know you commented him...

Comment: @NoIdeaForName thanks I wasn't aware of that. How can I stop the first if statement from overriding the second one?

Comment: specialLabel is a local declaration in each statement, so it can't be overridden

Comment: well... i'm no expert here, but let me write it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you'll change your code to:

```
if ([itemOnSpecial caseInsensitiveCompare: @"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    specialLabel.text = specialPrice;
    [specialLabel setHidden:NO]; 
    }
else
{


   if ([isOnBulkSpecial caseInsensitiveCompare:@"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
            specialLabel.text = bulkSpecialPrice;
            [specialLabel setHidden:NO]; 

   }else{
       UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
       [specialLabel setHidden:YES];
   }
}
```

then the second if statement will be called only if the first didn't pass. that way the `specialLabel.text` property will not be changed twice and the value will not be overridden in the second if

Answer (score 1):

Try the code like this:

```
if ([itemOnSpecial isEqualToString: @"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    specialLabel.text = specialPrice;
    [specialLabel setHidden:NO]; 

if ([isOnBulkSpecial caseInsensitiveCompare:@"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
            UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
            specialLabel.text = bulkSpecialPrice;
            [specialLabel setHidden:NO]; 

}else{
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    [specialLabel setHidden:YES];
}
}
```

Or like this:

```
   if ([itemOnSpecial isEqualToString: @"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
        specialLabel.text = specialPrice;
        [specialLabel setHidden:NO]; 
        } else if ([isOnBulkSpecial caseInsensitiveCompare:@"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
                specialLabel.text = bulkSpecialPrice;
                [specialLabel setHidden:NO];

    }else{
        UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
        [specialLabel setHidden:YES];
    }
```

I don't understand your script, but the first if statement have nothing to do with the second one in your code.

Comment: If I try the code with "else if" to start the second one specialLabel.text displays specialPrice instead of bulkSpecialPrice.

Comment: Can you, please, explain your script? And what you want those statements to do?

Answer (score 0):

The first statement will check case sensitive string while second statement will check case insensitive string.

when your `itemOnSpecial's` value is equal to only @"yes" in that case it will be enter inside otherwise it will skip while in the second case your string is equal to like @"Yes",@"YES",@"yEs",@"yeS" in all cases it will enter.

So i hope u understand my answer...

Comment: I just updated my question so that both statements are caseInsensitiveCompare. This is how i originally intended to do it. I changed it to isEqualToString to see if the code would work like that but it didn't. Doesn't work either way...

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on the first if condition and print the condition to see what it's returning. Then finish stepping through the code.

ex.

```
(lldb) p ([itemOnSpecial caseInsensitiveCompare: @"yes"] == 0)
(bool) $1 = true
```

Where NSOrderedSame == 0.